# on clicking UITextField, picker appears but kwyboard is not gone

Tags: iphone, uikeyboard

I have a table view containing 10 cells and each cell has a text field. Till textfield 5, I want the user to enter some value using keyboard. On text field 6, I want the user to select values from a list (showing picker view).
What is happening is when I click on field 5 (showing keyboard), entered some value and then hit return button (on keyboard), the keyboard goes down and then, I click on text field 6 (showing picker), the picker is shown (no keyboard appears here).

BUT if I dont hit return button of keyboard (on field 5) and directly click on field 6 (picker), then my picker appears with the keyboard at the top, that is, keyboard doesn't goes down and picker appears behind the keyboard. Here, when I click on return of keyboard, then also keyboard doesn't goes down. To make the keyboard go down, I need to click on any text field (showing keyboard) and then hit return.

Has anybody faced this strange problem?? Please help me out.

Comment: in my textfield's didBeginEditing delegate method, I am writing this code for showing the picker:

if (textField.tag==kStateTag) {
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   UIPickerView *stateListPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,160,320,216)];
   stateListPicker.tag = kStateListPickerTag;
   stateListPicker.delegate = self;
   stateListPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
   [self.view addSubview:stateListPicker];
   [stateListPicker release];
  }

Comment: I am doing alloc init for UIPickerView in this method and then, adding that picker on my view....

Answer (score 1):

you have to set the tag of each textfield and set the delegate and then put this delegate method like this,

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField

  {

  If (textField.tag == 6)

  ```
  {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
  }
  ```

  return YES;
  }

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Dont add the picker as a subview manually. Set it as the `inputView` of the text field (on `cellForRowAtIndexPath`) and the OS will take care of showing and hiding for you.

Comment: jrturton, I have added the text field on UITableViewCell's contentView, that is, the text fields I have added are all local. I had alloc init them in each rows and after adding them on my cell.contentView, I have released them. I have used tags for each of the text fields, and have added this code in my viewDidLoad method:
[((UITextField*)[tblTransferDetails. viewWithTag:kStateTag]) setInputView:stateListPicker];

but it isn't working. :(

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise it was in a table. In that case, do it at cellForRowAtIndexPath. If you hold the picker view as an instance variable you only need to create it once. Set the input view to nil if you want the keyboard to appear (if the cell is reused)

Comment: Hey jrturton, it worked man, but now the problem is the text field is allowing me to write in it (but keyboard is not showing). I dont want to let user write anything in this text field. He should select any item in the picker and then when he clicks outside the picker view, the picker should get disappear and the selected item should get displayed in the text field...

Comment: That should be a new question.